# How to know where to use css, less and Sass?

Tags: css, styles, sass, less

I have knowledge of HTML, CSS, and jQuery. Recently I knew about [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [less](http://lesscss.org/). As they both are the style sheet language I am a little bit confused about where to use both of them as CSS is already there and it is also widely used in every website. So how to know where to use these (Less, Sass) in that particular field.

Another doubt comes to my mind is, is it fine to use Sass and Less in [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) instead of default CSS?

Comment: LESS and Sass are CSS preprocessors, in the end it's still all CSS. The preprocessors add syntactic sugar to make CSS development less tedious.

Comment: before doing a down vote any suggestion or nay helpful link will be more helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As zzzzBov said, LESS and SASS are css preprocessors.

Basically, you pick one and write your style definitions in that language.  When done you run it through the preprocessor and it will generate a normal CSS file for you.  That normal file is what you would use in your site.

I'd highly suggest that you skip using SASS/LESS or any other preprocessor until you are more familiar with CSS in general.

---

A little more information about LESS.

LESS can be run ahead of time as an actual preprocessor OR you can simply link the less.js file and your .less file and let the browser do it.  The problem with letting the browser do it is that every single browser that hits your site, for every single page, will have to "recompile" the css in order to render your site correctly.  Considering you have zero control over the computers hitting your sites this might result in a "slow" site from some peoples perspective.

Further, that javascript only works in some of the browsers, further limiting it's usefulness.

Quite frankly, CSS is one of those things that you generally set up once for a site and leave alone for a year or more.  So, it may simply just not be worth it.

Comment: thanks for the reply..But as per my knowledge you have to write the total less in a file and after that you have to make that file link with the html...just like we do link a css file with the html?

Answer (score 4):

SASS and LESS are two Domain Specific Languages that are converted to CSS via a preprocessor. The preprocessor can run client-side in Javascript or server-side via PHP, Node.js, Rails, etc.

Either SASS or LESS would be excellent for a new project. Or if you're using a framework that makes use either technology. (Such as Bootstrap or Rails).

If you're modifying an existing web site which uses pure CSS (such as Wordpress) you should almost always extend and build off of the existing styles. Mixing plain CSS with SASS/LESS can be a mess especially if you are just learning the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Both are here to make your job easier //save time, make your CSS more readable, you will no longer forget colors/margins or specific values that you used, because you can create variables, mixins etc.

If you feel like you would benefit from any of features provided, why wouldn't you use it? It's not mandatory to use those, it's not like I would use CSS for every project I create (majority though). Try it out, it won't take more than an hour to know basic features.